# keyDown events not registering when form has buttons C#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm having to make a breakout style application in C# on a normal form, where the ball will move randomly if a button is pressed, or where a ball can be manually controlled if another button is pressed.  I'm having no problem randomly moving the ball around the screen and if there are no buttons on the form I can make the ball manually move around the screen.  Once I add the buttons though the keyDown event is never triggered.  I can't figure out how to set the focus to the form.

Basically, when my manual button is pressed I want to change the focus to the main form so I can detect key presses, something along the lines of:

```
    private void btnMoveBallManually_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ball.setManualBall = true;
        Form1.ActiveForm.Focus();
    }
```

I've read so many things about focus that I'm completely lost now, any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Ok, to clarify a bit.  To manually control the ball I have the following code to deal with key presses

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
        {
            up = true;
            down = false;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
        {
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            left = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.D)
        {
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = true;
            left = false;
        }
    }
```

then the following code in the timer deals with actually moving the ball

```
private void gameTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ball.getManualBall == true)
        {
            if (down) { ball.moveBallDown(); }
            if (up) { ball.moveBallUp(); }
            if (left) { ball.moveballLeft(); }
            if (right) { ball.moveBallRight(); }
        }
        else if (ball.getRandomBall == true)
        {
            ball.randomlyMoveBall();
        }

        ball.checkWallCollision();

        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

and button presses will either set ManualBall to true or will set RandomBall to true.

both work as required if there are no buttons on the form and the above bools are set manually prior to running.  With buttons, the random ball part works fine, but no matter what I try the manualBall part won't work as the form never registers the button presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `Form.KeyPreview` to true:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Comment: Not a good idea.  He's pretty likely to use the cursor keys, KeyPreview doesn't help to see those keystrokes.  Always avoid KeyPreview, it is a VB6 legacy property with odd VB6 semantics.  Override ProcessCmdKey() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure if it's some kind of obsolete feature but as the OP described it should work for him, even it's obsolete, I've not experienced any issue with it. Using `ProcessCmdKey` is some kind of overkill, could you tell me what the exact issue with KeyPreview? thank you!

Comment: Well, just try it.  Note how the KeyDown event doesn't fire for the cursor, Enter and Tab keys.

Comment: I've already tried setting the KeyPreview property on the form to true and doing it in the code as well to no avail.  where exactly should I set the property in the code?  At the moment I've got it under InitializeComponent();  Oh, and I'm using WASD, not the cursor keys to try and prevent any kind of problem.

Comment: @HansPassant the KeyDown is fired OK, Enter can also be handled in the KeyDown handler, the `Tab` key is some kind of very special key, even in normal control like TextBox, it seems unable to be handled in `KeyPress`, `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, so it's not a particular issue of KeyPreview, I don't want to mean it can replace the ProcessCmdKey, however we can use it in some cases.

Comment: @user3075259 what kinds of Keys are you trying to handle? Are you sure your Key related events handler are subscribed correctly?

Comment: So I want to control my ball like so:
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
            {
                down = true;
                up = false;
                right = false;
                left = false;
            }
which is repeated for each key WASD, W being up(and all others set to false etc.)

Comment: @user3075259 how do you know it's not fired? set some break point or ...?

Comment: Ah, ok I've tried your keypreview thing and now it is firing when I use a break point (it wasn't before).  Thanks alot for that, it was driving me crazy.  Now I guess I just need to step through the code and find out what else is wrong.  Cheers :)

Comment: Right, sorry about that I've been staring at this for so long that I didn't realize I'd renamed the button and the button press wasn't doing anything.  All working perfectly.  Sorry for being a bit of a muppet and Thank you so much King King for the advice.